# Converting open file to save file dialog not working

Tags: c#, wpf

So Dai fixed my problem with the openfiledialog but then i started working on save file,

here is the code i made but it did not work/ i can't think of a way to get it to work.

```
const String FILTER_LUA = "Lua scripts (*.lua)|*.lua";
            const String FILTER_TXT = "Text files (*.txt)|*.txt";
            const String FILTER_ALL = "All files (*.*)|*";

            // ...

            SaveFileDialog sfd = new SaveFileDialog()
            {
                //  InitialDirectory = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory,
                InitialDirectory = Environment.CurrentDirectory,
                Filter = FILTER_LUA + "|" + FILTER_TXT + "|" + FILTER_ALL,
                Title = "Open Script"
            };

            Boolean? result = sfd.ShowDialog();

            if ((result ?? false) && File.Exists(sfd.FileName))
            {
                String fileText = File.ReadAllText(sfd.FileName);
                this.TextEditor.Text = fileText;
            }
```

Comment: why are you doing ReadAllText intead of WriteAllText?

Comment: "So Dai fixed my problem with the openfiledialog" - answers which solve your issues can and should be accepted.

Comment: Ash what do you mean

Comment: He means that when there is an answer to your question that solves your problem, you should click the check-mark next to it so that it will be marked as the answer for all to see

Comment: oke i will do that, i am new to stackoverflow

Comment: No worries, we all had to learn this at one point or another.  You might find help-center articles like this useful - https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask  (Not saying you asked a bad question, just pointing it out)

Comment: SaveFileDialog is meant to pick a file path to save data to. In your case you would have to **write** the `TextEditor.Text` value to the picked file using `File.WriteAllText` or `File.WriteAllTextAsync`.

Comment: Also you don't have to check if the picked file exists. that is what the file picker dialog is for: to guarantee that the user picked file exists.

Answer (score 1):

`SaveFileDialog` is meant to pick a file path to save data to. In your case you would have to *write* the `TextEditor.Text` value to the picked file using the `File.WriteAllText` or the asynchronous `File.WriteAllTextAsync` method:

```cs
private const string FILTER_LUA = "Lua scripts (*.lua)|*.lua";
private const string FILTER_TXT = "Text files (*.txt)|*.txt";
private const string FILTER_ALL = "All files (*.*)|*";

private async Task SaveTextBoxToFileAsync()
{
  var sfd = new SaveFileDialog()
  {
    // InitialDirectory = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory,
    InitialDirectory = Environment.CurrentDirectory,
      Filter = $"{FILTER_LUA}|{FILTER_TXT}|{FILTER_ALL}",
      Title = "Open Script"
  };

  bool? result = sfd.ShowDialog();
  if (result ?? false)
  {
    await File.WriteAllTextAsync(sfd.FileName, this.TextEditor.Text);
  }
}
```

**Usage**

```cs
await SaveTextBoxToFileAsync();
```

Comment: I get an error:  Cannot await void

Comment: SaveTextBoxToFileAsync must return Task like in the example. Why is it void?

Comment: how would i do that, i am not the best with c#

Comment: Just look at my example. there is no void. SaveTextBoxToFileAsync returns Task. Then you can await it. If you are not able to fix it you must post your latest version so that I can review it. But you should be able to copy my version and use it.